# Python SqlAlchemy Update Statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Could anyone help me out with this update statement? Just trying to save json value as str into a column in my database, but its not going through:

```
    new_bookmarks = {
        fitness_discipline: {effort: str([x for x in options if x['value'] in values]).replace("'", '"')}
    }

    session, engine = db_connect()
    athlete_bookmarks = session.query(athlete.peloton_auto_bookmark_ids).filter(
        athlete.athlete_id == 1).first().peloton_auto_bookmark_ids

    athlete_bookmarks_json = json.loads(athlete_bookmarks)
    athlete_bookmarks_json.update(new_bookmarks)

    athlete_bookmarks = json.dumps(athlete_bookmarks_json)

    session.commit()

    engine.dispose()
    session.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-assigning the variable `athlete_bookmarks`, not setting the attribute `peloton_auto_bookmark_ids` on athlete:

```py
new_bookmarks = {
    fitness_discipline: {effort: str([x for x in options if x['value'] in values]).replace("'", '"')}
}

session, engine = db_connect()
athlete = session.query(athlete).filter(athlete.athlete_id == 1).first()

athlete_bookmarks_json = json.loads(athlete_bookmarks.peloton_auto_bookmark_ids)
athlete_bookmarks_json.update(new_bookmarks)
athlete_bookmarks.peloton_auto_bookmark_ids = json.dumps(athlete_bookmarks_json)

session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it with the following

```
    session, engine = db_connect()
    athlete_bookmarks = session.query(athlete.peloton_auto_bookmark_ids).filter(
        athlete.athlete_id == 1).first()

    # update peloton bookmark settings per the inputs
    athlete_bookmarks_json = json.loads(athlete_bookmarks.peloton_auto_bookmark_ids)

    # Check if fitness discipline exists
    if not athlete_bookmarks_json.get(fitness_discipline):
        athlete_bookmarks_json[fitness_discipline] = {}
    # Check if fitness discipline / effort exists
    if not athlete_bookmarks_json.get(fitness_discipline).get(effort):
        athlete_bookmarks_json[fitness_discipline][effort] = {}

    athlete_bookmarks_json[fitness_discipline][effort] = json.dumps([x for x in options if x['value'] in values])

    session.query(athlete.peloton_auto_bookmark_ids).filter(
        athlete.athlete_id == 1).update({athlete.peloton_auto_bookmark_ids: json.dumps(athlete_bookmarks_json)})

    # write back to database
    session.commit()

    engine.dispose()
    session.close()
```